# Invertir una cadena usando una función recursiva en c#

Tags: c#, string, funciones, recursión, optimizar

Les comento, a modo de hobby, estoy leyendo un libro de programación en C#. Ya voy por la sección en donde se me explica el concepto de recursividad y en está sección se me plantearon, entre otros, un ejercicio en el que se me pide crear una función recursiva que sirva para invertir una cadena. He logrado resolver el ejercicio, sin embargo tengo la sensación de que el algoritmo que implementé no es el mas eficiente, y podría hacerse en menos líneas. Mis preguntas son las siguientes:

**1-** Se les ocurre una mejor forma de resolverlo utilizando recursividad? (dejo el código que use al final).

**2-** Podrían darme algún consejo para entender bien la recursividad?. Soy bastante malo en matemáticas y en efecto se me está complicando bastante resolver este tipo de ejercicios incluso habiendo buscado mas info en otras fuentes, mi cerebro no lo quiere captar. Este ejercicio en particular me costo una hora resolverlo.

Estaré muy agradecido con su ayuda!!!

Esta es la función que creé para resolverlo:

```
using System;
using System.Text;

namespace Recursividad3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StringBuilder cadena = new StringBuilder("Esto es una frase");
            Console.WriteLine(Invertir(cadena));            

        }

        static StringBuilder Invertir(StringBuilder cadena, int cont = 0)
        {
            char temp;

            if(cont == cadena.Length / 2)
            {
                return cadena;
            }
            else
            {
                temp = cadena[cont];
                cadena[cont] = cadena[cadena.Length - 1 - cont];
                cadena[cadena.Length - 1 - cont] = temp;
                return Invertir(cadena, cont + 1);
            }

        
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Sí, se puede optimizar un poco y te quedaría:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string ToReverse = @"Quiero invertir esta cadena";
        Console.WriteLine($"Si se invierte \"{ToReverse}\", queda: \"{Reverse(ToReverse)}\"");
    }
    
    public static string Reverse(string value)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            return value;
        
        return Reverse(value.Substring(1)) + value[0];
    }
}
```

Si el compilador que estás utilizando te da error en la línea:

```
Console.WriteLine($"Si se invierte \"{ToReverse}\", queda: \"{Reverse(ToReverse)}\"");
```

puedes surtituirla por:

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Si se invierte \"{0}\", queda: \"{1}\"", ToReverse, Reverse(ToReverse)));
```

Esa implementación se aprovecha de que para invertir la cadena se extrae el primer carácter y se coloca al final. Si quieres ver los resultados parciales puedes incluir la siguiente línea al inicio de la función, justo antes de `if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))`.

```
Console.WriteLine( $"Cadena a invertir en este ciclo: \"{value}\"" );
```

Para entender cómo funciona la *recursividad*, se dice, debes enteder la *recursividad*... ;)

Recursividad, simplificando mucho, es tan sólo que una función se llame a sí misma después de haber realizado una transformación de sus datos de entrada. El ejemplo típico es el del cálculo de la función [factorial](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial), que en cada ciclo de cálculo se utiliza el resultado del ciclo anterior.